# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'miner_config'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run my project from Google Colab but I keep on getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'miner_config'. The structure of my project is:

```
import time
import hashlib
import json
import requests
import base64
from flask import Flask, request
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import ecdsa

from miner_config import MINER_ADDRESS, MINER_NODE_URL, PEER_NODES

node = Flask(__name__)
```

This is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-9f096205089b> in <module>()
      8 import ecdsa
      9 
---> 10 from miner_config import MINER_ADDRESS, MINER_NODE_URL, PEER_NODES
     11 
     12 node = Flask(__name__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'miner_config'
```

Comment: Why do you think the import should succeed? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: `miner_config` is not a built-in module.  You have to install it yourself.  Did you?

Comment: You could create this error with a single line of code.